# How do i change the search permanent links

Tags: url-rewriting, search

I have 3 custom searches created using different templates.

The search results page loads different results depending on the referrer:

```
<?
/* Template Name: Search Results */
$search_refer = $_GET["post_type"];

if ($search_refer == 'post') { 
    load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search/filme.php'); 
}
elseif ($search_refer == 'persoane') { 
    load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search/actori.php'); 
}
elseif ($search_refer == 'trailers') { 
    load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search/trailers.php'); 
}
?>
```

I'd like to make the url of this page prettier. Right now it looks like this:

```
/?s=After+Earth&post_type=post
```

but I'd like it to look like this:

```
/search/After+Earth/post_type/post
```

How do I make the url more beautiful?

Comment: This one may be helpful: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should solve your problem. Just put it into your functions.php file.

```
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['search/([^/]+)/post_type/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?s=$matches[1]&post_type=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );


function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules' );
```

You will have to flush rewrite rules after adding this code, before it will start to work. Just switch theme to another and back or go to Settings->Permalink Settings and push "Save" button.

Comment: this code don't works

Comment: Well, this one I checked, so I'm pretty sure it does, actually ;) You just have to be sure that rewrite rules are flushed correctly after adding it to functions.php file. Then you can go to yoursite.com/search/My+Query/post_type/post/ and it will return search results.

Comment: How i did, i upload to my function, i go to Permanent Link's click Save Changes, and i search another term. Shoud be fine but i retrive same... /?s=Movies&post_type=post

Comment: This code won't change your search form magically. It only assures that when you type in this url, WordPress will run appropriate search. So when you type this `/search/After+Earth/post_type/post` in your browsers address bar, the search for posts with "After Earth" will bu called. I have no idea how are you creating search urls (with a form, some links, or any other method) so I'm unable to help you with that part.

Comment: ok this is my form http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103828/how-can-i-add-a-jquery-to-my-search

http://postimg.org/image/a5jhe08if/6eb9968a/

Answer (score 0):

first of all ,see this url http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks ,and then goo to the admin dashboard Settings->Permalink Settings->Common Settings set the the url as you want,Have a try,just,may be it will help!

Comment: i know of that, the permanent link's are enabe  "/%postname%/"

Comment: Well, I don't think this would help. You can't set custom rewrites in settings part of dashboard.